# Symfony, how to add a field to the database that isn't on the form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I want to use a form in Symfony to allow a user to add admin clients. The User class contains fields `$username` (string), `$password` (string) and `$roles` (array of user roles).

I want to be able to enter the username and password in a form and then add this new user to the database but I don't want to have to enter the role on the form, I want to code this in to always be `ROLE_ADMIN`.

In my controller, I have the following code:

```
class SysAdminController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/sysAdmin", name="app_sysAdmin")
 */
public function sysAdmin(Request $request)
{
    
    $user = new User();
    
    $form = $this->createForm(AddAdminUserType::class, $user);
    
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $user = $form->getData();
        $user->setRoles(['ROLE_ADMIN']);
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();
            
        return $this->redirectToRoute('db_write_success_message');    
    }
        
    return $this->render('/sysAdmin.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}    
}
```

However, when I try to submit the form it gives the message "This value should not be blank." It appears to be related to the $roles field and is falling over on the `$form->isValid()` check. This field should indeed not be blank on the database, therefore in the User class is set to `Notblank`. However, I would like it to be blank on the form and then I'd like to populate this before adding it to the database.

Comment: AFAIK, you can just remove the field from `AddAdminUserType` and use `setRoles` like you did

Comment: if you want to be able to edit the roles in your form, just call setRoles before `$this->createForm(...)`. That way you set the "default" for the form, but you can still change it in the form. this way, it gets communicated to the form's user, that role_admin will be set on the user.

Comment: Thanks, calling setRoles before creating the form worked.
It wasn't listed as a field on AddAdminUserType, which was what was throwing me.

Answer (score 0):

In your entity User

Do u do this ?

```
 public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, exactly that.